# I want to Enter 100000 Records in Resource.Resx File and Access it Form Window Form in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, forms, resources

Although I have Accesed it.. but only upto 60000 Records can Access. whenever I Enterd 70000 Record ,it is Displaying Exception in Loading Page..
below-

System.TypeLoadException: 'Type 'WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Resources' from assembly 'WindowsFormsApp1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' contains more methods than the current implementation allows.'

I want to Enter 100000 Record in Resources File and Access  it From Window Form

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): why do you want 100,000 entries in a resource file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is abusing the resources system. It's not meant to replace a database or hold this much information - its designed to enable easy configuration, or multi-linguale applications where adding a language shouldn't force you to recompile.

Instead of using resources, try using something else - A JSON configuration file, a database, perhaps images directory - depending on your needs.